# C++ concept member check type ambiquity with reference

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am learning C++ concepts, and I have an obnoxious problem:

I do not know how to differentiate between member variable being variable of type `int` and member variable being a `int&`.

Reason for this is that check I am using is using instance.member syntax and in C++ that returns a reference.

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
void print(T t) {
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
requires requires(T t){
    {t.val} -> std::same_as<int&>;
}
void print(T t) {
    std::cout << "special" << std::endl;
}

struct S1{
    int bla;
};

struct S2{
   int val = 47;
};
int x = 47;
struct S3{
    int& val=x;
};

int main()
{
    print(4.7);
    print(S1{});
    print(S2{});
    print(S3{});
}
```

I wish `print(S3{})` would be handled by generic case, not the special one.
Note that changing my `requires` stuff to:

```
 {t.val} -> std::same_as<int>;
```

makes `S2` not match the template so that does not work(like I said I think that member access in C++ returns a reference).

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that expression concept checks use `decltype((e))` in the check rather than `decltype(e)` (the extra parentheses matter).

Because `t.val` is an lvalue of type `int` (expressions never have reference type), `decltype((t.val))` is `int&` regardless, as you've discovered.

Instead, you need to explicitly use the single-paren syntax:

```cpp
template <typename T>
requires requires (T t) {
    requires std::same_as<decltype(t.val), int&>;
}
void print(T t) {
    std::cout << "special" << std::endl;
}
```

Or

```cpp
template <typename T>
requires std::same_as<decltype(T::val), int&>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when `t.val` is `const`. Wouldn't it be more versatile or robust to apply something like `std::remove_cvref` to the type yielded from `decltype`, as in: `requires std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(T::val)>, int>`?

Comment: @303 What doesn't work when `t.val` is `const`? `decltype(t.val)` if `val` is a `const int` is still `const int`.

Comment: After reading the question more carefully, I think we both misunderstood OP's requirements exactly. The OP stated that he wanted `print(S3{})` to be handled by the generic case, while still having `print(S2{})` match the special case. This wouldn't work with your current solution, although it seems all there needs to change is to remove the reference qualifier, as in `requires std::same_as<decltype(T::val), int>`.

Comment: But this runs into the problem of not providing a match when `val` is defined with `cv` qualifiers. To avoid that, something like `requires std::same_as<std::remove_cv_t<decltype(T::val)>, int>` could be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
template <typename T>
requires requires(T t)
{
    requires std::is_same_v<decltype(t.val), int>; // or `int &` for references
}
void print(T t)
```

---

Clang has a bug that causes `{T::val} -> std::same_as<int>` to work as well, even though the type of the lhs is [said to be](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Compound_Requirements) determined as if by `decltype((...))`, which should return `int &` here.

---

Note that *"member access in C++ returns a reference"* is false. It can't be the case because [expressions can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1). When you write a function with a reference return type, calling it produces an lvalue of a non-reference type.

`decltype` will add reference-ness to the expression types depending on value category (`&` for lvalues, `&&` for xvalues, nothing for prvalues). That's why people often think that expressions can have reference types.

It also has a special rule for *variables* (as opposed to general expressions), which causes it to return the variable type as written, disregarding the *expression* type & value category. And apparently `t.val` counts as a variable for this purpose.

Comment: Looks like clang 13.0.0 has fixed the bug.