# Concept checking on struct members

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

What is the simple, idiomatic way, to check that a specific struct member validates a given concept ?

I tried the following and it does not work because `{ T::f }` yields type `float&`:

```
#include <concepts>
struct foo {
    float f;
};

// ok
static_assert(std::floating_point<decltype(foo::f)>);


template<typename T>
concept has_fp_member = requires (T t) {
  { T::f } -> std::floating_point;
};

// fails
static_assert(has_fp_member<foo>);
```

Where can I "remove" that useless reference being added on `{ T::f }` ? Without making the code super ugly, adding new concepts, etc... my main requirement is that things stay readable !

e.g.

```
template<typename T>
concept has_fp_member = std::floating_point<decltype(T::f)>;
```

is very subpar, because my actual concept would check a large set of attributes, and I do not want a mess of `std::foo<decltype(T::a)> && std::bar<decltype(T::b)> && ...`

Note that I use `float` as an example but my question is about a general solution for any type / concept.

Comment: the easiest one is perhaps `T::f` -> `+t.f`.

Comment: won't work if the member does not have an unary operator+ defined though.

Comment: "won't work" did you check that?

Comment: Does this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67369582/700825

Comment: Well, I don't find the answer satisfactory at all, I definitely don't want to write code like this  ! @康桓瑋's solution looks much cleaner

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier ecosystem-wise it's less cleaner as it is relying  on a macro.. but  using his decay function directly is variable.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but in similar situation I used `std:convertible_to`: e.g. `template <typename T> concept HasSomething = requires(T x) { { x.something } -> std::convertible_to<double>; };` which has advantage of avoiding macros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use macro:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
std::decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&&);

#define CHECK_MEMBER(name, type) \
{ decay_copy(t.name) } -> type

template<typename T>
concept has_member_variables = requires (T t) {
  CHECK_MEMBER(f, std::floating_point);
  CHECK_MEMBER(i, std::integral);
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/bbvb5vxM8)

Comment: since c++23, we can just do
```cpp
template <typename T>
concept has_member_variables = requires(T t) {
    { auto(t.f) } -> std::floating_point;
    { auto(t.i) } -> std::integral;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial solution but I would like to find something better (inspired from an answer to this question which has been removed)

```
auto prvalue(auto&& arg) { return arg; }

template<typename T>
concept has_fp_member = requires (T t) {
  { prvalue(T::f) } -> std::floating_point;
};

static_assert(has_fp_member<foo>);
```

It only supports cases where the member is copy-constructible though.